# How to add an event handler to an element which is rendered on a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two links on a page. When I click on the second link, it displays certain fields. I want to write a `onkeyup()` event handler for one of the fields. I have written the code like this and I'm missing something. Please help.

```
        var inputBox;
        $().ready(function() {

             //cc_sec is the id of the second link in my page.
             $('#cc_sec').click(function(){
               inputBox = document.getElementById("{!$Component.pg.pb.cardForm.cardnumber}");
               alert(inputBox.id);
               //This alert is giving me the ID of the element correctly.
            });   

            //This is not working. inputBox is declared as global variable.
            inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
                alert(inputBox.value);
                document.getElementById('printCardNo').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
            }

        });
```

Please point out my mistake. TIA :)

UPDATE:
I can get the element by ID only after clicking the `cc_sec` link. So I cannot do `inputBox = document.getElementById("{!$Component.pg.pb.cardForm.cardnumber}");` in the beginning of the `ready` function.

Comment: Value of variable `inputBox` is set after `click` event but you are assigning event listener in `ready` handler when `inputBox` is `undefined`

Comment: I agree with @RayonDabre - move the `inputBox = ` line to directly below the `$().ready(` line.

Comment: Are you telling that onkeyup handler should be within click event handler? I tried that also and didnt work

Comment: No - you need to assign the variable before anything else. Then you can add your event handlers.

Comment: @KallumTanton, I can get the ID of that element only after I click on the cc_sec link. So I need that click event to get the element by ID. Only after getting that element, I can use it for writing another event

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj so what happened when you placed the `onkeyup` declaration within the `.click` handler?

Comment: It wasn't calling the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

1. call document.getElementById in document ready:

   ```
   var inputBox;
   $().ready(function() {
        inputBox = document.getElementById("{!$Component.pg.pb.cardForm.cardnumber}");
        //cc_sec is the id of the second link in my page.
        $('#cc_sec').click(function() {
          alert(inputBox.id);
          //This alert is giving me the ID of the element correctly.
       });   

       inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
           alert(inputBox.value);
           document.getElementById('printCardNo').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
       };

   });
   ```
2. or set onkeyup in click event:

   ```
   var inputBox;
   $().ready(function() {

        //cc_sec is the id of the second link in my page.
        $('#cc_sec').click(function() {
          inputBox = document.getElementById("{!$Component.pg.pb.cardForm.cardnumber}");
          alert(inputBox.id);
          //This alert is giving me the ID of the element correctly.
          inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
             alert(inputBox.value);
             document.getElementById('printCardNo').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
          };
       });

   });
   ```

Comment: the second approach is working as per my requirement. I'm sure I tried this before, but I must have done some mistake at that time. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery `.on` to add eventhandler to dynamically created elements.

```
$('body').on("keyup","{!$Component.pg.pb.cardForm.cardnumber}",function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    document.getElementById('printCardNo').innerHTML = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: At no point does the OP say that it's a dynamic field. Your code does not solve the solution since the problem is the placement of the variable assignment. This solution would also require explanation of where to place this in his code. **Edit** - I see that the title refers to an element which is rendered on event trigger but his code does not do this.